# Layer Weight Shape (6,6) Not Compatible With Provided Weight Shape (6,)

Tags: numpy, keras, neural-network

I am trying to set custom layer weights in a keras sequential model.  However, in doing so I get the error "Layer weights shape (6,6) not compatible with provided weight shape (6, ).

I see there are other questions on here regarding that error.  But my issue is that I reshape my input array to (6, ) in my code.  Also, I am using sypder.  After running the code it shows the size of weights1 to be (6,) in the variable explorer window.  Also, as another check, I typed weights1.shape in the console, and got (6, ).

So it appears the shape of my weights array is in fact (6, ), but I am still getting that error.

Here are the parts of my code I think are relevant,  if I miss something just let me know:

```
population_size = 100
output11 = 1
activation = 'elu'
out_activation='sigmoid'
epochs = 500
opt = SGD(lr=.01, momentum =.9)
weights = [[]for _ in range(population_size)]


for i in range(population_size):
    for j in range(6):
        weights[i].append(random.uniform(0, 1000))


for i in range(len(array)):
    if i == 0:
        inc.append(0)
    elif array[i][4] > array[i-1][4]:
        inc.append(1)
    elif array[i][4] <= array[i-1][4]:
        inc.append(0)
    
    
inc = np.array(inc)
inc = np.reshape(inc, (-1,1))
array = np.hstack((array, inc))


input_train = array[0:1259,0:6]
output_train = array[0:1259, 6]
input_validate = array[1259:1887, 0:6]
output_validate = array[1259:1887, 6]
input_test = array[1887: , 0:6]
output_test = array[1887: , 6]


weights1 = np.array(weights[0])
weights1.shape = (6,)
out_test2d =np.reshape(output_test,(len(output_test),1))
out_train2d = np.reshape(output_test, (len(output_test),1))


weights1 = np.array(weights[0])
weights1.shape=(6,)
model = Sequential();

model.add(Dense(6, use_bias = False, name = "hiddenL1", input_shape = (None,6)) )
model.add(Dense(output11, use_bias=False, name="output", activation=out_activation))
print(model.summary())

opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, epsilon=None, decay=0.05, beta_1 = 1,beta_2 = .5,amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.layers[0].set_weights([weights1])
```

Comment: your first layer is a mapping from 6 input features to 6 hidden units, thus it is a 6x6 matrix. You can't assign a vector of length 6 to this. Are you confusing layers? Your second layer is 6 dimensions, so you need to do layers[1].set_weights

Comment: Ah okay.  That must've been the issue.  Thank you!